# Is the BehaviorBase<T> still available to be used on Prism for .Net MAUI?

Tags: maui, prism

I'm migrating an app, which uses uses Prism, from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI. One of the classes in the project inherits from the BehaviorBase<Xamarin.Forms.View> class to override the OnAttachedTo and OnDetachingFrom methods, but I can't find that class in the Prism version for MAUI. Is there any replacement for the BehaviorBase class? Has it changed how it works in Prism for MAUI?

Tried to look inside the Github code. and I found some references, but the BehaviorBase is unreachable, even from the Object Browser.
I also found this in the [Prism documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/behaviors/behaviorbase.html) but I don't know if its updated

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Does anyone have an idea how to go about it?